# Avoid slideshow div resizing according to displayed image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I did a slideshow with fade animation of images in a div. However, when the next image shows, the div gets smaller/bigger according to the image and the page auto-scrolls, and I do not want that. How can I avoid this?

I wrote a function that once the page loads, it finds the biggest image, and sets the div to have that height of that image so that whenever a new image shows, the div height does not change. However, the problem is when the browser gets smaller/larger, the value of the div's height does not change even though I am resitting it every time the browser changes the size using on resize listener ("biggestImage" variable).

**JQuery**

```
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();
divResizeIssue();

function showSlides() {
    var slides = $(".images");
    slides.each(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut(500).delay(490);        
    });

    slideIndex++;

    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1;
    } 
    slides.each(function(index){
        if(index == slideIndex-1){
            $(this).fadeIn(500).delay(490);
        } 
    });
    setTimeout(showSlides, 5000);
}

function divResizeIssue(){
    var biggestImage;
    var object;

    var slides = $(".images");
    var firstLoad = true;

    if(firstLoad){
        slides.each(function(index){
            if(index == 0 || $(this).outerHeight() > biggestImage){
                biggestImage = $(this).outerHeight();
                object = $(this)[0]
            }
        });
        slides.each(function(){
            if($(this)[0] != object){
                $(this).outerHeight(biggestImage);
            }
        });
        firstLoad = false;
    }

    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        biggestImage = 0;
        object = null;
        slides.each(function(index){
            if(index == 0 || $(this).outerHeight() > biggestImage){
                biggestImage = $(this).outerHeight();
                object = $(this)[0];
            }
        });
        slides.each(function(){
            if($(this)[0] != object){
                $(this).outerHeight(biggestImage);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="top-div" class="row">
        <div class="row">
            <h1 class="col-sm-12">Activities</h1>
            <span class="col-sm-2"><!-- <button class="leftButton"></button> --></span>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-8">
                <figure class="images">
                    <figcaption class="caption">Outdoor</figcaption>
                    <img class="img-fluid" id="Outdoor" src=".\src\Hiking.jpg">
                </figure>
                <figure class="images">
                    <figcaption class="caption">Indoor</figcaption>
                    <img class="img-fluid"  id = "Indoor" src=".\src\indoor.jpg">               
                </figure>
                <figure class="images">
                    <figcaption class="caption">Join Us!</figcaption>
                    <img class="img-fluid" id = "Member" src=".\src\member.png">        
                </figure>
            </div>
            <span class="col-sm-2"><!-- <button class="rightButton"> --></button></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#top-div {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top:90vh;
    background: #AB3F05;
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
}
figure img{
    padding-left: 5vh;
    padding-right: 5vh;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.images{
    position: relative;
}
```

If you have some better suggestion, please do suggest, or if you can tell me what's wrong with my code, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I did was harcoding height values when the screen size changes, I don't really like to hardcode it, but it's the only way I can think of right now.

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 576px) {
    /*Change slides height to 950px when at sm (576px)*/
    #top-div{
       height: 950px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
    /*Change slides height to 440px when greater than sm*/
    #top-div{
       height: 440px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, when doing slide shows it's much easier and looks nicer when you just manually resize the images to the same resolution using gimp or photoshop.

However if for whatever reason you can't do that you can use percentages in CSS to create dynamic lengths.

Here's what I came up with

```
//changed '.images' to '.image-container' also removed the divResizeIssue //function because we don't need it

var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
    var slides = $(".image-container"); //here
    slides.each(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut(500).delay(490);        
    });

    slideIndex++;

    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1;
    } 
    slides.each(function(index){
        if(index == slideIndex-1){
            $(this).fadeIn(500).delay(490);
        } 
    });
    setTimeout(showSlides, 5000);
}
```

#### CSS

```
#top-div {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top:90vh;
    background: #AB3F05;
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
}
figure img{
    padding-left: 5vh;
    padding-right: 5vh;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

/*Changed Below*/

.image-container {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

#### .image-container

the `width: 50%` makes it so the .image-container resizes when the browser viewport changes width. `margin: 0 auto` centers the .image-container inside it's parent.

#### .image

the `width: 100%` streaches the img tag to be the width of its parent (the .image-container).

the fixed `height: 400px` keeps tall images from expanding the height of the parent.

#### HTML

```
<div id="top-div" class="row">
        <div class="row">
            <h1 class="col-sm-12">Activities</h1>
            <span class="col-sm-2"><!-- <button class="leftButton"></button> --></span>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-8">
                <figure class="image-container">
                    <figcaption class="caption">Outdoor</figcaption>
                    <img class="image img-fluid" id="Outdoor" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
                </figure>
                <figure class="image-container">
                    <figcaption class="caption">Indoor</figcaption>
                    <img class="image img-fluid"  id = "Indoor" src="https://picsum.photos/300/300">               
                </figure>
                <figure class="image-container">
                    <figcaption class="caption">Join Us!</figcaption>
                    <img class="image img-fluid" id = "Member" src="https://picsum.photos/400/300">        
                </figure>
            </div>
            <span class="col-sm-2"><!-- <button class="rightButton"> --></button></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I just renamed the class="images" to class="image-container" and added an image class to the img elements, also changed the src on the images to use picsum so you might want to change them back.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but setting a fixed height for the images makes them squished when the browser gets smaller.